# I am facing an issue, when i create folder inside distribution for new files and projects tailwind is not working

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, tailwind-css

How to apply Tailwindcss CLI on multiple diffrent folders in distribution. Do i require to run commands every time?

When i try to run `npx tailwindcss -i ./source/input.css -o ./distribution/newFolder/style.css --watch`
It throws error on terminal

> style.css not found or does not exist.